# Boolean Value Changes on Exporting and Importing on PHP MyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have come through some strange situation as when I export my database through one computer to other, the boolean value changes from 0 to 1 automatically while the 1 value remains the same.

Any Suggestions please.

The database name on either computers are

```
  account_expired   bit(1)
```

Above listed is the field Name and Type.

The database is auto generated by Grails Application. Regards.

Comment: How do you export your database?

Comment: @MarcDelisle Through PHPMyAdmin